# How to implement Datastore in java based android app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, datastore, android-jetpack-datastore

I can only find ways to implement datastore through Kotlin. I have tried creating it with
`DataStore<Preferences> datastore = new Datastore<Preferences>` but as soon as proceed with it, it overrides to methods namely save and loadData but the parameters passed in them are also in Kotlin. Should I proceed with Sharedpreferences only?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with recommendations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are few steps to implement dataStore in java base.

First and foremost, it is good to notice that there are 2 different types of dependencies for the datastore.

1. TYPED datastore
2. Preferences DataStore (SharedPreferences like APIs)

Here are some steps to implement the latter one in the java based application.

**1. Implementation**

```
// Preferences DataStore (SharedPreferences like APIs)
dependencies {
  implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0-alpha06"

  // RxJava3 support
  implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-rxjava3:1.0.0-alpha06"
}
```

**2. Create a Preferences DataStore**

```
DataStore<Preferences> dataStore =
  new RxPreferenceDataStoreBuilder(context, /*name=*/ "settings").build();
```

**3. Write to a Preferences DataStore**

```
Single<Preferences> updateResult =  RxDataStore.updateDataAsync(dataStore, 
prefsIn -> {
  MutablePreferences mutablePreferences = prefsIn.toMutablePreferences();
  Integer currentInt = prefsIn.get(INTEGER_KEY);
  mutablePreferences.set(INTEGER_KEY, currentInt != null ? currentInt + 1 : 1);
  return Single.just(mutablePreferences);
});
```

// The update is completed once updateResult is completed.

**3. Read from a Preferences DataStore**

```
Preferences.Key<Integer> EXAMPLE_COUNTER = PreferencesKeys.int("example_counter");

Flowable<Integer> exampleCounterFlow =
  RxDataStore.data(dataStore).map(prefs -> prefs.get(EXAMPLE_COUNTER));
```

if you want to do more complex please checkout the full [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#preferences-datastore)

Comment: Does not explain how to set up a listener when Flowable is ready and the integer can finally be accessed.

Answer (score 2):

I am new to posting here, so I can not add a comment, but I want to build on the answer from Mehran.
Also the answer is old, so I do not know if this worked like that, but I noticed several things:

Now, you dont have to implement the alpha versions:

```
//DataStore instead of SharedPreferences
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0"
//RxJava2 support
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-rxjava2:1.0.0"
```

Furthermore, If you want to use the RxDataStore and the associated RxDataStoreBuilder the simple DataStore doesnt work:

```
RxDataStore<Preferences> dataStoreRX;
dataStoreRX = new RxPreferenceDataStoreBuilder(this,"datastorename").build();
```

To get data from the DataStore you can use:

```
value.blockingGet();
```

But there is way more to that. If you want to use the DataStore across several activities you need to use a Singleton. The reason is you cant create more than one instance of one DataStore. That is in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#preferences-datastore) but I think it is not complete.
Also error-handling is not described there.

I elaborate more on this here: [Link to Medium](https://medium.com/@deadmanapple/using-the-android-datastore-library-instead-of-sharedpreferences-in-java-d6744c348a05)

A little shame with the plug, but one shall not start a question here if there is no actual question. So I hope this helps people who want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the Medium post from @maxvolk I ended up with this:

```java
import android.content.Context;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.MutablePreferences;
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.Preferences;
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.PreferencesKeys;
import androidx.datastore.preferences.rxjava2.RxPreferenceDataStoreBuilder;
import androidx.datastore.rxjava2.RxDataStore;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import io.reactivex.Single;

public class DataStoreSingleton {
    private static final String STORE_NAME = "loggerStore";

    public static String PRIVACY_POLICY_ACKNOWLEDGED = "PRIVACY_POLICY_ACKNOWLEDGED";

    private static final Preferences pref_error = new Preferences() {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public <T> T get(@NonNull Key<T> key) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <T> boolean contains(@NonNull Key<T> key) {
            return false;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Map<Key<?>, Object> asMap() {
            return new HashMap<>();
        }
    };

    RxDataStore<Preferences> datastore;

    private static final DataStoreSingleton ourInstance = new DataStoreSingleton();

    // Private constructor because this is a singleton.
    private DataStoreSingleton() { }

    // Get the singleton instance.
    // If the instance hasn't been initialised yet, initialise it.
    public static DataStoreSingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (ourInstance.datastore == null) {
            ourInstance.datastore = new RxPreferenceDataStoreBuilder(context, STORE_NAME).build();
        }

        return ourInstance;
    }

    public boolean setStringValue(String Key, String value){
        Preferences.Key<String> PREF_KEY = PreferencesKeys.stringKey(Key);

        Single<Preferences> updateResult =  datastore.updateDataAsync(prefsIn -> {
            MutablePreferences mutablePreferences = prefsIn.toMutablePreferences();
            mutablePreferences.set(PREF_KEY, value);
            return Single.just(mutablePreferences);
        }).onErrorReturnItem(pref_error);

        return updateResult.blockingGet() != pref_error;
    }

    public String getStringValue(String Key) {
        Preferences.Key<String> PREF_KEY = PreferencesKeys.stringKey(Key);
        Single<String> value = datastore.data().firstOrError().map(prefs -> prefs.get(PREF_KEY)).onErrorReturnItem("null");
        return value.blockingGet();
    }

    public boolean setBoolValue(String Key, boolean boolValue){
        String value = boolValue ? "1" : "0";
        return setStringValue(Key, value);
    }

    boolean getBoolValue(String Key) {
        return getStringValue(Key).equals("1");
    }
}
```

It is used like this:

```java
DataStoreSingleton datastore = DataStoreSingleton.getInstance(this);
String foo = datastore.getStringValue("SOME_SETTING");
datastore.setStringValue("SOME_SETTING", "bar");
```